# Best way to have multiple custom domains associated with a site within a multisite installation

Tags: multisite

We have a multisite installation and would like to have multiple custom domains to be associated with one site. For example, www.example.com, prod.example.com and cdn.example.com should all point to the same site. What would be the best approach to achieve that? Based on what I see WP only allows one Site URL per site.

Also, just to put some boundaries around that question, because it is a multisite installation, there could also be another site with a different set of custom domains, i.e., www.example2.com, prod.example2.com and cdn.example2.com.

Redirects will not be a solution, since that is a default way how Wordpress handles such cases and that doesn't work for us.

It's good if there is a plugin for that, but more than happy to consider a code only solution with something going into `wp-config.php` file.

Comment: So you mean that visiting cdn.example.com would just show the exact same site as www.example.com? Not sure what the point of that would be?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The point is to have the same site to be accessible through CDN (cd.exampl.com) and bypassing CDN (prod.example.com). For example, admins should not be getting cached content from CDN, so prod would work better for them. There are other reasons too.

Comment: Just pointing a URL named CDN to the same website is not what a CDN is. What are you ultimately trying to achieve here?

Comment: That is understandable and beyond the scope of this question. Obviously, cdn domain will pass through CDN, while prod will point directly to an origin.